# How do I use Cohen's Kappa as a metric in a keras model for continuous output?

Tags: keras, tensorflow, metric

I am using keras to train a CNN on a dataset. The output should be a value from 0 to 4 and my training y values are integers in that range. I want to create a custom metric that rounds and clips my conintuous output to an integer value in that range and calculates a cohen kappa value.

### custom_metrics.py

```
def cohen_kappa_integerized(y_true, y_pred, num_classes=5, weights=None, metrics_collections=None, updates_collections=None, name=None):
    kappa, update_op = tensorflow.contrib.metrics.cohen_kappa(
        y_true, 
        clip(rint(y_pred), 0, 4), 
        num_classes, 
        weights, 
        metrics_collections, 
        updates_collections, 
        name
     )
     K.get_session().run(tensorflow.local_variables_initializer())
     with tensorflow.control_dependencies([update_op]):
         kappa = tensorflow.identity(kappa)
     return kappa
```

My code returns a value that does not match up to my accuracy metric very well so it "seems" to not be working. I pieced this together from a few sources and have never written a custom metric before, so a basic mistake is likely.

Here are the metrics from my run.

### cohen kappa

[image: Cohen Kappa]

### mean squared error

[image]